# Add a column in my dataframe based on the name of Excel file

Tags: python

I want to import many excel files into one single dataframe and I want a column where all the rows are the same as the original excel file name in python

this is what i have tried

```
df_final=df_final.assign(Année='2021')
df_final=df_final.assign(Mois='Octobre')
```

But I am obliged each time to imort a single excel file add these two columns and then move on to the next one.

How can i automate this into one function ?

Comment: Oops you forget to add how your sample data frame looks like

Answer (score 0):

in order to add a value to each dataframe based on the filename you need to create a list of values equal to the number of rows. Below is a simple example assuming the dataframes are the same.

Each sample file I have created looks like this:

file1.xlsx

```
   Some Data
0          5
1          3
2          2
3          3
4          6
5          5
```

file2.xlsx

```
   Some Data
0          6
1          8
2          5
3          4
4          5
5          9
```

Example code:

```
import pandas as pd, os

source_folder = r"\PATH\TO\FILES"

# Create empty list for the dataframes
df_list = []

# Loop though each file in the folder
for file in os.listdir(source_folder):

    # Create full file path
    file_path = os.path.join(source_folder, file)

    # Create dataframe
    x_df = pd.read_excel(file_path)

    # Create new dataframe column for filename based on the number of rows in dataframe
    x_df["filename"] = [file for _ in range(x_df.shape[0])]

    # Add dataframe to the list
    df_list.append(x_df)

# Concatonate the list of dataframes to a single dataframe
final_df = pd.concat(df_list)

print(final_df)
```

The final result is:

```
   Some Data    filename
0          5  file1.xlsx
1          3  file1.xlsx
2          2  file1.xlsx
3          3  file1.xlsx
4          6  file1.xlsx
5          5  file1.xlsx
0          6  file2.xlsx
1          8  file2.xlsx
2          5  file2.xlsx
3          4  file2.xlsx
4          5  file2.xlsx
5          9  file2.xlsx
```